# Can I say " becoming from X to Y"?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, verbs, prepositions

Is this period grammatically correct?

The tower, built for military purposes, has undergone numerous changes, **becoming from** clock tower **to** bell tower of the church of St. Giustino.

If it is not correct, which verb could be used as a valid alternative?

Comment: Since you already state "undergone," do you need another verb at all (changes, from clock tower)? Could you use 'ranging' or 'repurposed'?

Comment: leave out becoming.  "....numerous changes, from clock tower to...."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becoming is not appropriate here.

Become doesn't work across multiple objects. You can 'become' something, but you can not become from 'something' to 'something'.

> The tower, built for military purposes, has undergone numerous
>   changes, **morphing** from clock tower to bell tower...

Works well here, and conveys the idea that the tower is essentially the same tower with different characteristics and use now.

[Morph](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/morph)

> 1.1 Undergo or cause to undergo a gradual process of transformation.